# Convert dictionary into list based on the keys

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to convert my dictionary into list, with the same order of keys and values and inserting the line after end of each key values.

For example, I have the following:

```
mydict = {'Ball' : ['red', 'green'], 'Bat':['white', 'black'], 'wickets': ['white']}
```

I am trying to make as follows:

```
reqlist = ['Ball','red', 'green','\n', 'Bat','white', 'black', '\n', 'wickets','white', \n']
```

This is the code, I have tried:

```
reqlist = []
for k,v in mydict.iteritems():
    for val in v:
        reqlist.append([k+val+'\n'])
```

But, I do not get the expected output.

Pleased to hear some suggestions.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending the key each time you are appending a value. Just pull it out of the loop, along with the new line.

```py
reqlist = []
for k,v in mydict.iteritems():
    reqlist.append(k)
    for val in v:
        reqlist.append(val)
    reqlist.append('\n')
```

Comment: Could also do `sorted(mydict.iteritems())` to get the exact output the OP wants. Since dicts are unordered, the output is not guaranteed to be the same

Comment: Ah! Interesting. Didn't know about that. Your way is definitely more Pythonic.

Comment: It turns out that `iteritems()` does not work with Python 3.x. The new call is `items()` but I do not see `\n` being appended exclusively.